# Powershell SQL Server Read-SqlTableData converting Numeric to Decimal

Tags: sql, powershell

I am using PowerShell and the latest `SqlServer` module. The `Read-SqlTableData` call has changed two `numeric` columns to `decimal`. Thus data that previously showed as 23 now shows as 23.0000000 when `Write-SqlTableData` is used (full disclosure: write was to a fresh table name, PS version 5.1.18362.1110 on Windows 10).

Either this is a bug or a known limitation...

Is there a work around like changing the Powershell `System.Decimal` for the column to `System.Int32` or can someone help on what the SQL query would be to change the data type of a decimal column to a numeric in a table?

Thanks

Comment: `numeric` and `decimal` are synonymous in SQL Server. The thing you need to control is the scale parameter

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in my case to change the column back to what it was originally. System.Numeric does not seem to exist in Powershell so probably why this happened.

```
use Confluence_Sandbox2
ALTER TABLE cwd_user_new
ALTER COLUMN id NUMERIC(19,0)

ALTER TABLE cwd_user_new
ALTER COLUMN directory_id NUMERIC(19,0)
```

This from the internet is what i used to see the datatypes before and after

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,
DATA_TYPE,
IS_NULLABLE,
CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
NUMERIC_PRECISION,
NUMERIC_SCALE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='your_table_name';
```